# Split and Transpose multiple columns

Tags: javascript, split, formula, transpose

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16L48iNAFn1LRQNakLK47bdPgf1SX3bF4w9Q6ON6AQy8/edit?usp=sharing

Here is a link to what I need to do. Not sure if it can be achieved by a formula or a script.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest to achieve this goal by javascript is to:

1. Save the file to csv file
2. Read the csv file and split the csv file row by row, column to column.
3. Extract the data in the column and split out into rows.
4. Write the result back to the csv file.

Here is the example JS code to implement that.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const file = fs.readFileSync("./Test page - Sheet1.csv", { encoding: "utf-8" });

let rows = file.split("\n");
let last = rows.pop();

let newRows = last
    // split by column by comma
    .split(/,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))/)[7]
    // remove the "  
    .replace(/^"(.+?)"$/, "$1")
    // split the data by comma
    .split(",")
    // mapped the items into rows
    .map(item => {
        let newRow = Array.from(last.split(/,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))/));
        newRow[7] = item.trim();
        return newRow.join(", ");
    });

// save back the data into the file
fs.writeFileSync("./Test page - Sheet1.csv", rows.concat(newRows).join("\n"));
```